# Volume of the solid where it is enclosed from $2x + y + z = 4$ and the planes $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $z = 0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, volume

> Calculate the volume of the solid where it is enclosed from $2x + y + z = 4$ and the planes $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $z = 0$.

My approach:

For $z = 0$:
\begin{equation*}
2x + y = 4 \implies y = -2x + 4
\end{equation*}

and for $y = 0$:

\begin{equation*}
2x = 4 \implies x = 2
\end{equation*}

So the integral for the volume are:

\begin{equation*}
  \int_0^2 \int_0^{-2x +4} \left(4 - 2x - y\right)\,dy \,dx
      = \frac{16}{3}
\end{equation*}

Is my approach correct? If not, can you provide the correct answer?

Comment: @SarGe Is my approach correct? And finally i used MathJax :)

Comment: The volume is an irregular tetrahedron and can be computed directly to be $\frac{1}{3}\frac{4\times 2}{2}\times 4=\frac{16}{3}$.

Comment: @Patricio Okay. But my solution with integral and the edges of them are correct?

Comment: It is, the point is that you could have double checked your result (what were the odds of obtaining the right solution if your work was wrong?).

Comment: @Patricio sometimes it is possible :). Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct and you can calculate it also as
$$\int\limits_{0}^{4}\int\limits_{0}^{2-\frac{y}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{4-2x-y}\,dy\,dx\,dz=\int\limits_{0}^{4}\int\limits_{0}^{2-\frac{y}{2}}(4-2x-y)\,dy\,dx =\int\limits_{0}^{2}\int\limits_{0}^{4-2x}(4-2x-y)\,dx\,dy$$